# Windows 7 network settings profiles

Tags: windows-7, networking

I would like to have various "profiles" for my network settings -- one for work, one for home network, etc. Changing a "network profile" would change my IP address and DNS server address for a network adapter, and if possible add or remove a route.

Is there some free software for that purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some free products that can switch between configurations for network settings, including even printers and shared folders :

[Eusing Free IP Switcher](http://www.eusing.com/ipswitch/free_ip_switcher.htm)
[NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/index.php?s=nsm)

[image]

Comment: Note that NetSetMan is free only for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 4):

[TCP/IP Manager](http://tcpipmanager.sourceforge.net/) seems to satisfy the reqirements. <del>[Netprofiles](http://code.google.com/p/netprofiles/) also seems to work, but just for LAN connections under Windows 7.</del> *Netprofiles could not start on Windows 7 x64*

Answer (score 2):

I've never personally used it, but [Avanquest Connection Manager](http://www.avanquest.com/USA/software/avanquest-connection-manager-107347) might meet your needs:

> When you connect for the first time
>   from a new location, Avanquest
>   Connection Manager automatically
>   selects the best available network.
>   Connect quickly and easily to public
>   WiFi hotspots in coffee shops or
>   airports, in your hotel while
>   travelling, when at home or in the
>   office.
>
> Avanquest Connection Manager detects
>   your preferences for set up of
>   printers, email, disk drives for each
>   location, and saves them. When you
>   come back to a location, with
>   Avanquest Connection Manager, your
>   default printer, email accounts,
>   security settings, your web browser,
>   and others, are automatically
>   configured.
>
> Detect, select and securely connect
>   your laptop to different networks and
>   peripherals automatically.